# Does **Impractical** here mean the computation is based on dataset/observations

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, terminology

This [CMU machine learning textbook](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/mlbook/NBayesLogReg.pdf) says

> Unbiased Learning of Bayes Classifiers is Impractical

Does **Impractical** here mean the computation is based on dataset/observations?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it means that it requires observations; actually, too many observations for a *realistic* case to be *practically* feasible, although it works in theory or for toy/unrealistically small problems.